# Localstack + aws cli 2 : Facing and error connection closed before received a valid response from endpoint url http://localhost:4572

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, localstack

Hi I am new to below these installed the localstack/localstack-full and aws cli2 . Trying to add aws secret key but it throws an error like below

**console**

```
D:\aptsmt\docker\localstack>aws --endpoint-url http://localhost:4572 --region eu-west-1 secretsmanager create-secret --name dummy-secrets --secret-string file://secrets.json

Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL: "http://localhost:4572/".
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this version localstack/localstack:0.10.1.2 and works for mes

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack}"
    image: localstack/localstack:0.10.1.2
    hostname: localstack
    networks:
      - localstack-net
    ports:
      - "4566-4599:4566-4599"
      - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sns,dynamodb,s3,sqs,lambda,cloudformation,sts,iam,cloudwatch,apigateway,events
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - PORT_WEB_UI=8080
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker-reuse
      - LAMBDA_REMOTE_DOCKER=false
      - LAMBDA_REMOVE_CONTAINERS=true
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=${TMPDIR}
    volumes:
      - ./data:/tmp/localstack
      - ./bin:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d
networks:
  localstack-net:
    external: false
    driver: bridge
    name: localstack-net
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rerun and add `--overwrite`. Sometimes the localstack is slow especially if we run other items too.